# Excel: Criar escala com 2 pontos conhecidos

Tags: microsoft-excel, matemática

Ola,

Estou com um problema - q acredito ser muito mais matematico do que uma formula no Excel.

Tenho uma lista com percentuais de resultados e preciso "escalonar" esses valores de acordo com dois pontos conhecidos.

o VALOR MINIMO = 25 PONTOS

o VALOR MAXIMO = 99 PONTOS

e ai todos os valores entre precisam ser escalonados de acordo com essas duas referencias.

Sei que se fosse apenas o valor Maximo (ou apenas o minimo) - uma regra de tres seria suficiente pra escalonar tudo.

ex:

VALOR MAXIMO =  54% = 99 PONTOS.

entao para 50% - numa regra de tres - 91,67 pontos.

sendo a formula:

```
X = (99 x 50) / 54
```

minha duvida é como conseguir a escala se tivermos tb o VALOR MINIMO..

por exemplo

VALOR MAXIMO = 54% .... 99 PONTOS

VALOR MINIMO = 12% .... 25 PONTOS

quantos pontos valem 42%? 23%?

juro q estou queimando a cuca.. kkkkk

obrigado
Daniel

Comment: Sua pergunta está confusa, 54% equivale a 99 pontos? Exponha o contexto em que isso se insere e poderemos ajudar melhor :)

Comment: oi @LeandroFelipeMoreira primeiramente, obrigado pela ajuda! a duvida é simples (a solucao tb deve ser pra quem entende de matematica) - eu tenho uma escala fixa de pontos que varia de 25 a 99 pontos. e eu tenho um indice de aproveitamento que varia de 12% a 54% - ou seja - o menor aproveitamento entre todos da lista é 12% - o maior 54%. Eu preciso equivaler as duas escalas - pra isso eu tenho esses 2 pontos de comparacao - ou seja - 12% que é o minimo ira receber na escala de pontos - 25 pontos q é o minimo la. Ja 54% que é o maximo de aproveitamento - recebe 99 pontos.

Comment: Ai eu preciso converter todos os valores que estao entre 12-54% na escala de aproveitamento para receber os pontos respectivos (entre 25-99 pontos). Por exemplo, de cara eu ja sei que 33% vai equivaler a 62 pontos (pq é o valor MEDIANO de cada escala) - (54+12 = 66/2 = 33%) e (99+25 = 124/2 = 62 pontos). Mas para um aproveitamento de 45% - por exemplo - qtos pontos eu devo atribuir proporcionalmente na escala de pontos?

Comment: Respondi ali em baixo, não coloquei na formula, mas mostrei como funciona o calculo.

Answer (score 2):

Então, você tem duas escalas:

Pontos:

`25 Pontos - 99 Pontos, sendo seu centro 66 Pontos e seu range 74 Pontos (99 - 25 = 74)`
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porcentagem:

`12% - 54 %, sendo seu centro 33% e seu range 42% (54 - 12 = 42)`
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora pense em quanto seria 25% na escala de pontos? Não podemos simplesmente dividir 62(50%) por 2, o correto seria pegar `62 - 25 = 37` e dividir `37 / 2 - 18,5` e colocando na escala ficaria:

`25 + 18,5 = 43,5`.

Até aqui tudo bem.

> **Quanto equivale 25% na escala de Pontos**

Vamos utilizar o Range dos pontos para simplificar os cálculos em regra de 3.

`(74 * 25) / 100 = 18,5` - Regra de 3 entre `74 (range)`  `25 (porcentagem)`

Esse `18,5` representa quando deve ser adicionado a partir dos 25 Pontos para alcançar 25% dentro da escala, ou seja 43,5 Pontos.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> **Calculando outros valores**

`Quanto 45% na escala de porcentagem reflete na de pontos.`

Primeiro você converte 45% dentro da sua escala, no Range:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Faz a regra de 3:

`(33 * 100) / 42 = 78,57`

Tendo quantos % equivale dentro de seu range, agora você transfere a % para a outra escala:

`(74 * 78,57) / 100 = 58,14`

Como dito ali em cima, você soma isso com o valor minimo para acertar dentro da escala. No caso `25 Pontos + 58,14 Pontos = 83,14 Pontos`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Acho que é isso. :)

Answer (score 0):

Eu não consegui entender bem a sua pergunta, mas pelo que parece, talvez uma solução plausível seja trazer seu valores primeiramente para 0.
Seu valor minimo atualmente é 25, se 25 é o minimo entendo que seria o 0%.
Seu valor máximo atualmente é 99, se 99 é o máximo entendo que seria o 100%.
Para facilitar as contas você poderia definir o valor minimo como 0, logo fazia:
minimo - 25 = 0
máximo - 25 = 74

Subtrai 25 de todos os valores calcule os percentuais, ao fim você poderá fazer o calculo inverso adicionando 25.